# ElasticSearch Query Optimisation

Tags: amazon-web-services, performance, elasticsearch

I am trying to understand if the following 2 versions of the same query have any performance impact on search.

On a high level I am testing if [ A AND (B OR C) ] approach and [ E OR F ], where E ~ [A AND B] and F ~ [A AND C] approach of writing the same query has major performance impact and which one is a better way to go about it.

> CASE 1 - [amount > 100] AND [ (clientId =2 and country = EU ) OR
> (exchangeCurrency = EUR)]

> CASE 2 - (amount > 100 AND clientId =2 and country = EU) OR (amount >
> 100 AND exchangeCurrency = EUR)

```
"query": {
"bool":
  {
  "must": [
    {
      "range": {
        "header.amount": {
          "gte": 100
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "bool":{
        "should": [
          {"match": {
            "header.currency": "EUR"
          }},
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {"match": {
                  "header.clientId": 2
                }},
                {
                  "match": {
                    "header.country": "GB"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match" : 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

}
And the same query in a different way

```
"query": {
"bool": {
  "should": [
    {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "range": {
              "header.amount": {
                "gte": 100
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "header.clientId": 2
            }
          },
          {
            "match": {
              "header.country": "GB"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "bool" : {
        "must": [
          {
            "range": {
              "header.amount": {
                "gte": 100
              }
            }
          },
          {"match": {
            "header.currency": "EUR"
          }}
        ]
      }
      
    }
  ],
  "minimum_should_match" : 1
}
```

}

Comment: I suggest you [profile both queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/xpack-profiler.html). What do you find out?

Comment: I am missing the Profiler tab on Dev tools as mentioned in the link. I am using Version: 6.5.4, how to enable that?

Comment: In 6.5, you can use the [profile API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-profile.html) directly

Comment: I checked the profiling results but what I am not able to understand is that in Case 2 where it is having overlapping children for queries, does it cache the filter results and use that for children of the other OR condition? Which in this case would be caching the results for amount > 100

Comment: The Profile API won't tell you anything about how caching kicks in. Also, the profiling API introduces a non-negligible overhead that isn't there without profiling. The idea here is just to give you an idea if both queries perform similarly or if there's a big difference. I think they should perform similarly because queries are [not sensitive to boolean logic](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-query-execution-order). It was in the past, where [It was important to properly order the queries](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-optimizing-elasticsearch-searches), but not anymore

Comment: I think the links you provided talked more about order of conditions (A AND B) vs (B AND A). 
What i am trying to get to is a bit different from that.

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you is that ES takes care of that so you don't have to. Imagine the nightmare if people need to master the specifics of boolean logic in addition to the query DSL. Makes no sense. What you're asking there is a non-issue

Comment: I had a similar opinion on auto query optimisations done by indexing engine but couldn't find proof

Comment: The first link I gave contains a few optimizations they do under the hood.